# Auto Layout how to move the view2 from right to the bottom?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two views in the cell at the left  `UIImageView` and at the right `UIView` Containing some other views as in picture

[image]

Now I want if the width of Cell is => 300 then `View2` should be at the right of Screen as it is in picture other wise it should be moved to the bottom of `View1`

Answer (score 5):

Do one thing. Set another constraints for that view

1) leading to main view

2) top to imageview (you can give this constraint by right click from view to drag imageview then vertical spacing.)

Now give outlets for this two constraints programatically.

And also give outlets for constraints which are:
1) leading from view to imageview
2) top of view.

Now as per your requirement,set if condition

e.g.

```
if(width => 300)

{

topOfViewToImageviewConstraint.isActive = false

leadingOfViewToMainViewConstraint.isActive = false

}

else

{

leadingOfViewToImageViewConstraint.isActive = false

 topOfviewToMainView.isActive = false

 leadingOfViewToMainViewConstraint.constant = 0

 topOfViewToImageviewConstraint.constant = 20

}
```

Comment: can i achieve this through auto Layout or  adaptive Layout?without doing the changes in code behind

Comment: this is for auto layout.

Comment: i mean without changing the constraints in code as this https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started article suggests

Comment: you dont need to change constraints just add two more constraints which I said in answer

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  I am not currently in Xcode, so this is just some sample code, but the idea will work.
in `cellForRowAt`
check if `self.tableView.cellForRowAt(IndexPath.row).frame.width => 300`
if it is, make no change, but if it is not find the y coordinate of the bottom of view 1 and make a new rect at `(x: 0, y: botOfView1, width, height)`.  Then set the frame of view 2 equal to that.