# UILabel on second line if the content doesn't fit in the view's first line

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

The best way to describe my situations is with images. What I have is a view which contains several `UILabel`s and `UIImage`. The red box is a `UILabel` and if the content is too big it should go to the second line.

From the storyboard I have a working case when the content fits but the problem is that I am not sure how to handle the case when the last (red box) should go to the second line. I am using `autolayout` and `cartography`.

If someone can point me to the right direction I will be very grateful.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to make two line text in single label? If so then you can make it possible by setting numberOfLine = 0. Is that what you need?

Comment: use constrain greater then equal and http://stackoverflow.com/a/39888662/6656894 refer this

Comment: @Janmenjaya, no I don't want that. I just want to move the whole label on the second line if ti's too big.

Comment: Go with Himanshu's answer if you want to make the label start from where it is and will be expanded till second line.
Or else connect your constraint as outlet and manage yourself to make the constraint bigger.

Comment: No, that's not a solution. It will be ok if the UILabel is the only view inside the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calcululate width of text as per your current label's position.

If text width is more than current label's width then see my answer from below link:

[Auto Layout how to move the view2 from right to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329996/auto-layout-how-to-move-the-view2-from-right-to-the-bottom)

Calculate width:

```
func widthForView1(_ text:String, font:UIFont, height:CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{

let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: your_label_width, height: your_lable_height))
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
label.text = text
label.font = font
label.sizeToFit()
return label.frame.width
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer and I manage to do it in this way but how to properly check whether the uilabel right corner is not going over the parent width?

Comment: the width is always the same. I am printing the width after sizeToFit() and no matter what I put as a string it's always the same. I mean the value from label.frame.size.width.

Comment: calling layoutSubViews() before that fix the problem

Comment: let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height))   try this..

Answer (score 0):

Use of tag View can solve this issue. TagListView is an external library. 
When u add a view as subclass of taglistView, its height automatically increases accordingly.

ADD this to pod file : pod 'TagListView'

```
func addTags() {
        let str1 = "Hi"
        tagListView.addTag(str1)
        let str2 = "Helloo"
            tagListView.addTag(str2)
        let str3 = "How Are u ? "
        tagListView.addTag(str2)
        tagListView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. Could you please give some more info

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with constraints only. To change the entire position of the element on the screen, you need to do it programmatically.

Comment: that's ok. But I would like to know what would be the best, right and easy way. Just the logic

Comment: The logic would be the following
1. Place LABEL on line1 (e.g. in Storyboard)
2. Set LABEL's text
3. Consider its size (does it fit or should it be replaced?)
4. If size == OK -> leave it as it is
else -> replace the label

To do that you might need to store some constraints as properties (e.g. LABEL's top constraint and Line2 2 view's top constraint)